# Only display Hide/Show button if on Mobile/Tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/NCj2u/

Currently it works on *all* platforms, but I'd prefer if the show button & hidden content only worked in Tablet & Mobile. Desktop would show the content automatically and hide the button.

Can someone explain how I do this? Would I use media queries or do this in my Javascript?

My **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
    //get collapse content selector
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

    //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
    var toggle_switch = $(this);
    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
      if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                        //change the button label to be 'Show'
        toggle_switch.html('Show');
      }else{
                        //change the button label to be 'Hide'
        toggle_switch.html('Hide');
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery - Start here

Comment: Can you add a small class at the top level by detecting the user-agent in the backend. say for example <body class="mobile">. If you can then the solution is pretty easy. you can do a $('body.mobile .nav-toggle') instead of $('.nav-toggle')

Comment: You could use $.browser but be aware that its been deprecated in the newer versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm there are few options you could try . I personally recommend against browser detection unless you want to specifically target only a browser that allows your implementation. For your requirement why not try media queries?

```
 .nav-toggle{
   display : none; // display none for everyone
 }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet  show the button */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

 .nav-toggle{
   display : block; // or inline-block or inline : which ever is appropriate for you.
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

With these scripts you can detect any mobile browser
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
I think the shortest solution is to ask for mobil browsers and if the user isn't using one execute the `click()` function of your button